# Xcode 10 parallel test suite testing is slower with a low number of tests

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, ios-simulator, xcode10

In Xcode 10 (currently beta 1) I have turned on parallel testing for test suites for my iOS project.

"Edit Scheme" > "Test" > "Info". Check the tick "Execute in parallel on Simulator"

[image]

This feature was introduced to reduce the testing time by starting multiple simulators at once to spread test suites on them. (Not to be confused with parallel testing introduced in Xcode 9, that didn't include test suite spreading).

I have 200 tests and these are my results:

- 0.6 seconds without parallel execution
- 0.9 seconds with parallel execution

So obviously this is not working correctly. I thought maybe it has to do with the simulator's startup time. But that is not part of the calculation of execution time. So, either it is a bug in the beta version of Xcode 10 or I didn't set it up correctly.

Answer (score 4):

There is some overhead. XCTest needs to clone the simulator so the state is identical between each instance. Each clone has to finish booting.

It is up to you to see if parallelization improves the execution time of your tests or not. UI tests are almost always faster. Unit test results depend on the details of your project and the tests it runs.

Answer (score 2):

I just also made extensive tests in a medium-sized project with around 250k lines of code and I noticed something very similar. While building (clean build and incremental builds) was about the same speed as Xcode 9.4 I also saw around 20% slower running tests.

Note though that the project has relatively few tests and that Apple usually improves performance between beta 3 and beta 6 since beta 1 and 2 are here mainly to provide us new features. So let's see how this will change with the next betas ...

I also didn't see the "eight simulators on one screen" feature like in the demo, did you?

Comment: You're right. We should wait right now. I saw 3 simulators pop up for my tests.